# "service -s" not working inside Docker container

Tags: docker, installation

I found an issue when using the same image on a different PC (same Linux version and same Docker version), causing different results when executing  `service -s` in Docker.

I am using `docker attach xx` to execute this command.

Works fine on PC 1:

```
service -s 
Checking for udevd:                                                              unused 
Checking for Cron:                                                               unused 
Checking for service D-Bus daemon                                                unused
/etc/init.d/network is disabled, 
can't find any another service enabled as the network.service.
Checking for mounted nfs shares (from /etc/fstab):gssd not running 
idmapd not running
Warning: portmap/rpcbind not running - nfs may not work well
                                                                                unused
Checking for UPS monitoring service                                             unused
                                                                                unused
                                                                                unknown
Checking for service sshd                                                       unused
```

Fails on PC 2:

```
service  -s 
Failed to get D-Bus connection: No connection to service manager.
```

`docker system info` output in PC 1:

```
Containers: 6
 Running: 3
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 3
Images: 55
Server Version: 17.10.0-ce
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: false
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 06b9cb35161009dcb7123345749fef02f7cea8e0
runc version: 0351df1c5a66838d0c392b4ac4cf9450de844e2d
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 apparmor
Kernel Version: 4.2.0-27-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 16
Total Memory: 47.16GiB
Name: hadoop3
ID: 4WGL:SPWW:7IFX:ENVE:7742:VB37:A4VY:HUI4:S74E:RYIS:Q4DS:6BQO
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: No swap limit support
```

`docker system info` output on PC 2:

```
Containers: 1
 Running: 1
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 2
Server Version: 17.10.0-ce
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: false
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 06b9cb35161009dcb7123345749fef02f7cea8e0
runc version: 0351df1c5a66838d0c392b4ac4cf9450de844e2d
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 apparmor
Kernel Version: 4.2.0-27-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 16
Total Memory: 55.03GiB
Name: hadoop1
ID: ZAYC:DRNC:HJGM:MFKP:JBKS:SAMB:U4WZ:5E7L:RR2B:PJFN:EH4D:GGOA
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
 File Descriptors: 22
 Goroutines: 30
 System Time: 2017-11-12T23:00:09.145808427+08:00
 EventsListeners: 0
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: No swap limit support
```

The following is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM opensuse:13.1
RUN zypper -n install net-tools tar python-xml python rsyslog sudo nfs-client
RUN zypper -n install wget vim less tcpdump aaa_base openssh
RUN zypper -n install syslinux

WORKDIR /root

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]
```

I already try to reinstall Docker on PC 2 several times, but it isn't working out at all.
Please help me, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The "service" command will actually forward all calls to "systemctl" which in turn will forward it to the SystemD daemon. It will reach the SystemD daemon by using the messagebus, aka kernel-dbus. The error "Failed to get D-Bus connection: No connection to service manager." simply says that the SystemD daemon is not running which is normal in a docker container.

I don't know why the first call had worked altogether. You may try if it helps in both cases to follow the steps of using https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-replacement to avoid service/systemctl wanting to access the messagebus.